# Как изменять размер видео внутри VideoView на устройстве?

Tags: mediaplayer, android, videoview

Для изменения размера видео расширила класс `VideoView`, переопределила `onMeasure` следующим образом:

```
@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec)
{
    setMeasuredDimension(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
}
```

На эмуляторе размер видео изменяется, на устройстве же изменяется только размер самого `VideoView`, видео же умещается в него не меняя соотношения сторон.

P.S. Оказывается, даже на одной приставке все изменяется как надо, а на другой(нужной) не хочет, причем версия андроид на них одна и та же - 4.0.4.

P.P.S. Простой код:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    final public String TAG="VVActivity";

    MediaPlayer mMediaPlayer;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        SurfaceView surface = (SurfaceView)findViewById(R.id.surface);
        SurfaceHolder.Callback callback = new SurfaceHolder.Callback(){

            @Override
            public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format,
                    int width, int height) {}

            @Override
            public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {

                 mMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
                 mMediaPlayer.setDisplay(holder);

                 try {
                    mMediaPlayer.setDataSource("/mnt/sdcard/file.mpg");
                    mMediaPlayer.prepare();
                    mMediaPlayer.start();
                 } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {

                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (SecurityException e) {

                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IllegalStateException e) {

                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
            }};

            surface.getHolder().addCallback(callback);
    }

 }
```

Тоже работает, на одном устройстве, а на другом соотношение сторон не изменяется. Так что дело здесь не в `VideoView`.
Пробовала на видео разных по разрешению и даже по формату, все так же.

Comment: Может дело в самих файлах видео?

Comment: Если так, та в чем там может быть дело? Проигрывается поток в стандартном h.264.

Comment: Я бы попровал с помощью ffmpeg переконвертировать видео в меньшее разрешение, которое подойдет для мобильного устройства(исходя из разрешения 320х480 хотя бы). Если дело не в VideoView, то значит в самих файлах.

Answer (score 1):

> VideoView (or the SurfaceView for use with MediaPlayer) will be the size you tell it to be in your layout. Within that space, the video will play back as large as possible while maintaining the aspect ratio.

Таким образом, если видео полностью помещается в текущий размер *VideoView*, то дальше оно масштабироваться не будет.

> Оказывается, даже на одной приставке все изменяется как надо, а на другой(нужной) не хочет, причем версия андроид на них одна и та же - 4.0.4.

Подозреваю, у них разное разрешение экрана.

Comment: Вот именно что при сохранении пропорций. Мне же нужно, чтобы пропорции не сохранялись. 
Если сделать маленькое VideoView, например 200dpx200dp, то есть такое, что видео в него явно не помещается, видео уменьшается, но соотношение сторон не меняется.

Comment: Посмотрите http://blog.kasenlam.com/2012/02/android-how-to-stretch-video-to-fill.html.

Или же вам, возможно, нужен MediaPlayer, у которого есть метод setVideoScalingMode.

Comment: по ссылке: Sorry, the page you were looking for in this blog does not exist. 

((

Не хотелось бы использовать отдельно MediaPlayer. Может быть этот режим внутри класса VideoView или наследника от него можно заюзать...

Comment: Прошу прощения, случайно попала точка в конец ссылки. Исправил.

А чем вам не нравится вариант использования MediaPlayer?

Comment: Спасибо за ссылку. Как я понимаю, совет в этой статье сводится к тому что нужно использовать RelativeLayout и привязывать края видео к краям это layout'а. У меня так уже сделано)) 
MediaPlayer не хотелось бы использовать потому, что тогда нужно переписывать всю работу с видео без очевидных преимуществ.

Comment: Оказывается, setVideoScalingMode, появляется только в апи 16, а у меня апи 15, так что этот метод использовать нельзя.
К тому же, как я понимаю, он дает на выбор два режима: заполнять поверхность или обрезать видео. По умолчанию стоит заполнять, но ведет он себя в зависимости от устройства по разному.